# Memory leak Xamarin React Binding

Tags: macos, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross, model-binding

I am facing a memory leak issue in the following code. *An extract from the real code.*

In the `CountChanged` binding I am seeing a memory leak but for the `ItemChanged` there is no such leak. What shall I do to fix this?

```
private IDisposable _whenActivated;
public MyWindowController(MyViewModel viewModel) : base("MyWindow")
{
    ViewModel = viewModel;
    _whenActivated = this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
    {
        var mainThread = RxApp.MainThreadScheduler;

    //release issue starts
        this.WhenAnyObservable(
            x => x.ViewModel.MyArray.CountChanged)
            .SubscribeOn(mainThread)
            .Subscribe(x => _myListView.ReloadData())
            .DisposeWith(disposables);
    //release issue ends

        // Below is very similar to above, but no leak
        this.WhenAnyObservable(
            x => x.ViewModel.MyArray.ItemChanged)
            .SubscribeOn(mainThread)
            .Subscribe(x => _myListView.ReloadData())
            .DisposeWith(disposables);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are they any other particulars observers for CountChanged ? This code looks fine to me, I think the probleme has its roots somewhere else

Comment: @FlorianBurel: Observable in the same class or entire project?

Comment: I would say any other class that subscribe to the particular event CountChanged in your entire project

Comment: @FlorianBurel: I checked no where else it is observed.